# Server to test my app

Tags: git, heroku, github, branch, git-checkout

I am trying to upload my app on Heroku, but when I clone it from Github I get the following errors:

```
error: unable to create a file (Permission denied)
fatal: unable to checkout working tree
warning: Clone succeeded but checkout failed
```

Maybe the problem can be that I can edit only two branches of the project, neither of which is the master one.

What can be the problem and do you know another platforms like Heroku, where I can upload my app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From [the Heroku docs](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/git):

> Branches pushed to Heroku other than `master` will be ignored by this command. If you’re working out of another branch locally, you can either merge to master before pushing, or specify that you want to push your local branch to a remote master.

So you need to push to Heroku's `master` if you want anything to work. Note that you can push a local branch to a remote branch with a different name, as the documentation goes on to suggest:

> To push a branch other than master, use this syntax:
>
> ```
> $ git push heroku yourbranch:master
> ```

This should let you get code in a local non-`master` branch running on Heroku.

Comment: thank you for the information. I need to clone a different branch than master from GitHub, but I'll push it later on to the master branch of Heroku.